# handling Concurrency in SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have one question for you, if you can answer and refer resource it will be great help.

I have a scenario where i need to create a appointment slot and a serial no for each slot memberwise.

ex:

Member Id |App Slot #

1|1

1|2

2|1

2|2

1|3

what im doing is take the Max slot number,increamenting it and insert it memberwise. but the problem is concurrent user can create a slot when i take the max slot after that if any other user insert the slot the value that im working with is no more valid, how to over come this problem

Thanks & Regards,

Sameer

Answer (score 1):

Do all your work inside a transaction. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize the call to this code. You can do that by setting the isolation level of this transaction to Serializable. refer [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259216%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

There are side effects of using Serializable isolation level as it is the most restrictive mode of isolation. Use this isolation level for a very short duration to avoid blocking.